# Remove an array in an array by based on a keyed value in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to put together a shopping cart system using Laravel.

Here is how things are added:

```
public function addItem($itemId, $details = []) {
    if(isset(Session::get('cart'))) {
        Session::push('cart', ['item_id' => $itemId, 'details' => $details]);
    } else {
        Session::put('cart', ['item_id' => $itemId, 'details' => $details]);
    }
}
```

I know how to drop everything from the cart which is simple by doing:

```
if(isset(Session::get('cart'))) {
    Session::forget('cart');
}
```

But I don't know how to go about removing a specific item from the cart based on its `item_id`, currently all I have for this function is:

```
public function removeItem($itemId) {
    if(isset(Session::get('cart'))) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

How can I unset and item in the cart based on the key `item_id` in the sub array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Session` facade has a `forget()` function with lets you remove an item from the session. The cool thing about it, is that it internally calls [`array_forget`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#arrays) which allows you to use the "dot" notation. So this is how you do it:

```
$index = null;
// find out the index of the item to delete
foreach(Session::get('cart') as $i => $item){
    if($item['item_id'] == $itemId){
        $index = $i;
        break;
    }
}
// remove by index using the dot notation
if($index != null){
    Session::forget('cart.'.$index);
}
```

Also you could simplify things by using the `item_id` as actual array key. This should work:

```
public function addItem($itemId, $details = []) {
    Session::set('cart.'.$itemId, ['item_id' => $itemId, 'details' => $details]);
}

public function removeItem($itemId) {
    Session::forget('cart.'.$itemId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know currently there is no way to remove value of array stored in session, but you can try workaraound - load all array from session, remove the array value and set array back to session. Something like this should work:

```
public function removeItem($itemId) {
    if(isset(Session::get('cart'))) {
        $cart = Session::get('cart');
        unset($cart[$item_id]);
        Session::set('cart', $cart);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use array_forget function for dropping a nested array but you can remove a part using array_except like this:

```
$array = array_except($array, array('keys', 'to', 'remove'));
```

SO in your case use:

```
Session::array_except('cart', ['item_id', $itemId, 'remove']);
```

for more details please visit this link http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers

Comment: Whats with the 'remove' at the end?

Comment: Is it more like Session::array_except('cart', ['key', 'value', 'key', 'value]);?